# Нужны ли указанные запятые? (2)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, деепричастный-оборот

Будьте добры, подскажите, нужны ли указанные запятые?

**Они бежали, пока не добрались до дома и(,) лишь заперев дверь(,) посмели перевести дыхание.**

Answer (score 1):

Они бежали, пока не добрались до дома, и, лишь заперев дверь, посмели перевести дыхание.

"Они бежали и посмели перевести дыхание" - главная часть предложения; "пока не добрались до дома" - придаточное; "лишь заперев дверь" - деепричастный оборот.